# Using web APIs with limited website access (raspberry pi)

Tags: python, api, raspberry-pi, spotipy

I'm using a raspberry pi as a server to host a program. Part of what this program does is interface with websites such as spotify, google sheets, and google forms through their respective APIs (or a library wrapper)

In order to interface with spotify, i've attempted to use a python module called 'spotipy' which is a wrapper for the spotify API. However, i'm having trouble getting it to work, and I have a feeling its because the API requires authentication which utilizes the systems browser, i.e. chromium on the pi, but chromium does not have support for open.spotify.com due to its limited capabilities.

Is it reasonable to say that a web API wont work without access to the website you are attempting to interface with?

Hopefully this is provides enough information, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

github.com/plamere/spotipy#quick-start

to answer your question, you don't need chromium to use APIs. According to the quickstart that I linked above

1. you need to register your raspberry pi as an App on spotify dev site and acquire the "credentials"
2. then declare those credentials in your script